# Java - setting background color of a specific cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have the below shown code:

```
if ("1".equals(tmp.get(h))) {
   tmp2[0][h] = 1;
   for (int j = 0; j < truthTable.getModel().getColumnCount(); j++) {
      renderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer) truthTable.getCellRenderer(0,
            j);
      renderer.setBackground(Color.yellow);
   }
}
```

The `getCellRenderer` method contains the parameter row and column and is supposed to set the row 0 with a yellow background but instead it sets the whole table in yellow background. I'm confused so what is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

JTable cell renderers are not components but rather something more akin to rubber stamps that use a component to draw itself multiple times in your JTable. If you set the renderer's background to yellow and don't unset it if it's not the cell of interest, then it will remain yellow when drawing *all* cells.

Comment: prepareRenderer can do that +1

Comment: so what would be the best solution for this? or how can set the renderer to only one cell and not the whole table?

Comment: I'm going to ask the resident JTable expert, @mKorbel, to address this if he doesn't mind.

Answer (score 2):

Point the mouse at the table.

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class SingleCellColor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String[][] data = {
                        {"a", "1","2","3"},
                        {"b", "3","4","5"},
                        {"c", "6","7","8"}
                };
                String[] columns = {
                    "Letter", "Num 1", "Num2 ", "Num 3" 
                };
                DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);

                final SingleCellRenderer renderer = new SingleCellRenderer(); 
                final JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
                table.setDefaultRenderer(new Object().getClass(), renderer);
                table.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
                        Point p = me.getPoint();
                        renderer.setColumnHightlight(table.columnAtPoint(p));
                        renderer.setRowHighlight(table.rowAtPoint(p));
                        table.repaint();
                    }
                });
                JScrollPane tableScroll = new JScrollPane(table);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tableScroll);
            }
        });
    }
}

class SingleCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int rowHighlight = -1;
    int colHighlight = -1;

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus,
            int row,
            int column) {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        c.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        if (c instanceof JComponent) {
            boolean isFocused = (colHighlight == column && rowHighlight == row);
            ((JComponent)c).setOpaque(isFocused);
        }
        return c;
    }

    public void setColumnHightlight(int colHighlight) {
        this.colHighlight = colHighlight;
    }

    public void setRowHighlight(int rowHighlight) {
        this.rowHighlight = rowHighlight;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very good answer (1+), but it again runs into the problem of your losing the non-default renderers such as the number renderer. Note that all numbers are left-justified even if you give your DefaultTableModel class an appropriate `getColumnClass(...)` method override.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  Maybe I should have waited to see what the table guru advises.  ;)  (Just thought I'd toss that code out there, for experimentation.)

Comment: +1, in the constructor are (... boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) all these value are about this question, In most cases doesn't matter if is there (I love...) prepareRenderer or getTableCellRendererComponent, Advantage is that prepareRenderer can highlighting whole row more easilly (for me)

Comment: @mKorbel  The guru has spoken!  I must examine those table examples of yours more closely.  ;)